# VS 2019 v16.8 build, MVC forms and javascripts stop working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

Problem:

- If I build the project with VS2019 v16.8.2 and run the webapp then some of the
  forms on MVC page stop working (click on button with type="submit"
  and nothing happen, doesn't send any request to server) and also
  jquery validations on page stop working.

Found out:

- This is happening if I allow optimalizations in webconfig by removing debug="true" (from <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>). If I build and run
  app with debug="true", html forms and other things work fine.

Application info:

- Azure Cloud Services (1x WebRole, 2x WorkerRole)
- MVC version: 5.2.7.0
- .NET Framework: 4.6.2

I am still at the beginning of investigation. Have anyone the same experience or have you already found the solution?

I build and deploy app using Azure DevOps and the build is also make by the newest version of VS2019 and I have this bug also in Production.
A few weeks ago I was struggeling with another bug related to new version of VS2019 16.8 that caused failing build for Nuget lower than 5.8.0 so there is probably more issues with the new VS version or .NET 5.0 SDK.